# the best way to handle

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, extjs, web, linq-to-sql

I am writing a module(frontend extjs 4.2.1, backend asp.net mvc with the EF). I meet a little problem:
    when the user clicks the search button, a panel of extjs will be displayed and he/she can fill some blanks inside the textfield. after the filter information was submitted, the sever side will use appropriate c# code to deal with it to filter some records from the mssql database, here is my problem:

if the user inserts nothing into the field, the standard and best practice will be that this field will be neglected, however, the blank textfield's value will be '' which I can not use this as the filter string, for instance:
there is a textfield named "sex", if the use types nothing into the field, the value passed to server will be '', if i write the lambda expression in this way: 
var filter = x=>x.sex ==""; Apparently it will not work. You may say that i can use if-else to condition out the stuff. but if i have numerous fields, using the if-else will be really waste of time. 
so, what is the best practice to do this

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to write this condition, but what you're talking about is *a condition* so it's not really "a waste of time" to write the code for it.

For example, if you have an `IEnumerable<T>` and you want to filter it, you might do something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(someFieldValue))
    result = result.Where(x => x.SomeField.Equals(someFieldValue));
```

Or if you're building up expressions, you might conditionally define the expression.  Which might look something like this (this is entirely freehand, so I'm not sure it would work like this, but you get the idea):

```
var filter = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(someFieldValue) ?
             x => true :
             x => x.SomeField.Equals(someFieldValue);
```

You can abstract this behind some private helper methods so that consuming code is a bit cleaner, you can refactor commonly-handled filters to reduce duplication, etc.  But at the end of the day the logic your code is expressing is:

> In a specific known state, do one thing.  In other states, do something else instead.

That's a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

It can be prevented at client side before request submitted to server.

At server side , You can abstract validation part from service layer.

In my Typical Spring MVC application - 
1.Request goes to controller.
2.Controller delegates to Validator.
3.If success, controller delegates to service layer.
4.If failure, controller redirects user to error page.